# How to apply the Visual Studio theme to a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to correctly style a WPF ListView in a Visual Studio toolwindow so that it responds correctly to the active Visual Studio theme?

I am trying to achieve something like in the VS Task List tool window:

[image: Visual Studio Task List Window]

I've found this style [VsResourceKeys.ThemedDialogListViewItemGridStyleKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsresourcekeys.themeddialoglistviewitemgridstylekey) but it does not produce anything like it.

Here is what I achieved so far:

[image: Current ListView with bad style]

Almost everything is wrong:

- The grid view header is gray and it should be black.
- The grid view columns header text is black and it should be white.
- The items text is blue when the item is not selected and it should be white.
- Etc.

The list view is defined in XAML as follows:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="listDetails"
    Grid.Row="4"
    Height="150"
    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewDefaultStyleKey}}"
    >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Property"
                Width="150"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyName}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewGridViewColumnHeaderDefaultStyleKey}}"
                />
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Type"
                Width="150"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TypeName}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewGridViewColumnHeaderDefaultStyleKey}}"
                />
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Left Value"
                Width="150" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LeftValue}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewGridViewColumnHeaderDefaultStyleKey}}"
                />
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Right Value" 
                Width="150" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RightValue}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewGridViewColumnHeaderDefaultStyleKey}}"
                />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewItemDefaultStyleKey}}" />
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The styles are defined as follows:

```
<Style
    x:Key="{x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewDefaultStyleKey}"
    TargetType="{x:Type ListView}"
    >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsui:EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowBackgroundBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>

<Style
    x:Key="{x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewItemDefaultStyleKey}"
    TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static vsshell:VsResourceKeys.ThemedDialogListViewItemGridStyleKey}}"
    >
</Style>

<Style
    x:Key="{x:Static theming:StyleKeys.ThemedListViewGridViewColumnHeaderDefaultStyleKey}"
    TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"
    >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsui:EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowBackgroundBrushKey}}" />

</Style>
```

Is there any default style to achieve the correct behavior? Or any documentation on what to change in the styles?

Comment: Please share the namespace like theming, vsshell, vsui, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some documentation on the [VS Color Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/colors-and-styling-for-visual-studio#BKMK_TheVSColorService) and the [Shared VS Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/shared-colors-for-visual-studio). The shared vs color documentation should be enough to get you the right color names to use for your control.

Typically, you will need to set Foreground, Background, and Border colors for your controls. Then, have triggers that change those colors based on selection, mouseover, disabled, etc.

As long as you are using the VS Color Service, your UI colors will change automatically for High Contrast mode, so you do not need to handle that yourself.